# SSIS failure flow error. The decision after a sequence container failure does not proceed with the correct flow

Tags: sql-server, ssis, constraint, sequence, containers

I have an SSIS sequence container that extracts data from individual source database tables into a Stage layer. However, I need to know when a given calculation crashes in order for the given error to be written to the configuration table, which is provided by the yellow highlighted task in which the procedure is called. The problem is that if a given container falls due to an error, it does not flow through failure precendence constraint into the given task (LogPackageFailed).

I tried setting FaiPackageOnFailure together with FailParentOnFailure to TRUE in the properties, but it didn't help. The proposed solution in the following links does not work either:

- http://techblog.elish.net/2010/12/ssis-foreach-loop-container-continue-on.html
- https://simonworth.wordpress.com/2009/11/11/ssis-event-handler-variables-propagate/

, which was addressed in a previous similar query.

[image: SSIS-fail]

Comment: Can you post or doublecheck all of your expressions leading into the task? It's possible that it is not executing because of how they are configured, and not something on the package level.

Answer (score 0):

I would look at the event handlers (Package explorer tab shows this nicely). Something in there might be tamping down the failure or the DWH_STAGE container might have an explicit return status.

Something is off because a minimal reproduction works as expected

[image]